# Comparing two dataframes in pandas for all values greater than the other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames with numeric values.

I want to compare both of them and check if one has all values greater than the other.

I have a formula say where mean is mr and variance is vr and alpha is a scalar value, then I want to check if the dataframe r > (mr + alpha * vr) where mr is a dataframe with mean values and vr is variance dataframe. R is an individual dataframe for comparison.

```
if(r>(mr+alpha*vr)) :
   do something
```

For example my r DataFrame is `r=pd.DataFrame({"a":[5,1,8,9,10],"b":[4,5,6,7,8],"c":[11,12,12,14,15]})` and the other part entirely on the right is say `toCompare=pd.DataFrame({"a":[6,7,8,9,10],"b":[2,3,5,6,6],"c":[4,5,17,8,9]})`

So `r>toCompare` should result True,since elements in "b" are greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to just check if all values are True in the DataFrame. I got this to work finally. It was a bit difficult to figure in the large piece of code.

```
any((r>(mr+alpha*vr)).any())
```